# cakephp 3.0 theme plugin

Tags: plugins, themes, cakephp-3.0

I am following this tutorial - http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2014/07/21/themes-in-cakephp-3-howto/

I setup everything as per instructions using the bake tool, except for the following:

```
$this->viewBuilder()->theme('mytheme');
```

I added the above line to `beforeRender` method in the main application's `AppController.php`

When I access localhost/app/posts. I see the following:

```
PostsController could not be found.
```

I created the PostsController and still see the issue. I dont think its a permissions issue cause the main app loads fine. I have looked at several questions on SO about this issue but none of the answers fixed my code.

Any suggestions?